# Dropping wifi, replace bcm4331 with bcm4360, MacBook Pro Retina Early 2013

Tags: wifi, hardware

I have a MacBook Pro 13" Retina, Early 2013, my wifi drops roughly ever 2 or 3 minutes when running ArchLinux (OS X works fine). As far as I know this problem is related to that there are no official drivers available and thus there are no solution out there.

So the idea I have is to replace the BCM4331 with a BCM4360 or another alternative that works in ArchLinux and OS X. Is this possible? Would e.g a BCM4360 work in a MBPr Early 2013 with OS X?

Best regards
Rawa

Answer (score 1):

The BCM4360 is known not to work with the b43 driver. The broadcom-wl driver *should* work, but since the card is even newer, I would expect even more problems. I suggest to pick up a cheap usb wifi stick, that fixed all my problems.